# Removing observations based on leverage values

Tags: r, linear-regression

After inspecting my data, there seem to be quite some larger than expected (or hoped) leverage values in my `lm()` model. I wish to remove them based on which observation has exceeded the leverage threshold.

```
df <- df[ df$title_year >= 2000 , ] 
model <- lm( df$gross ~ . , data= df ) 

lev <- hatvalues( model3 ) 
lev_val <- lev[ lev > 2 * 8/2546

> names(lev_val)
  [1] "282"  "90"   "103"  "25"   "189"  "53"   "147"  "51"   "1526" "1"    "133"  "34"   "273"  "1852" "2172" "5"    "916"  "200"  "79"   "50"  
 [21] "29"   "632"  "266"  "149"  "28"   "26"   "107"  "105"  "202"  "144"  "203"  "8"    "414"  "54"   "279"  "394"  "4"    "155"  "10"   "1539"
 [41] "27"   "1318" "153"  "109"  "1790" "1327" "918"  "1275" "1055" "85"   "11"   "1543" "919"  "33"   "481"  "759"  "43"   "2404" "30"   "920" 
 [61] "212"  "123"  "42"   "223"  "58"   "118"  "111"  "32"   "281"  "88"   "1075" "1061" "421"  "1517" "487"  "2084" "774"  "934"  "1069" "86"  
 [81] "113"  "221"  "37"   "60"   "112"  "304"  "1347" "117"  "697"  "102"  "1472" "225"  "773"  "2"    "219"  "121"  "151"  "1856" "18"   "122" 
[101] "182"  "518"  "1084" "2014" "776"  "300"  "71"   "125"  "2070" "1854" "97"   "1288" "38"   "1087" "2004" "227"  "1747" "64"   "98"   "264" 
[121] "23"   "1729" "150"  "65"   "1559" "36"   "52"   "13"   "128"  "328"  "39"   "524"  "886"  "613"  "2195" "2441" "2446" "2096" "84"   "1522"
[141] "15"   "1800" "462"  "41"   "1100" "1804" "14"   "162"  "1336" "232"  "2193" "24"   "529"  "2088" "787"  "68"   "433"  "785"  "66"   "1340"
[161] "1863" "1587" "788"  "950"  "2450" "1717" "158"  "682"  "2531" "951"  "1110" "535"  "539"  "1478" "35"   "72"   "2136" "547"  "1887" "21"  
[181] "2208" "1873" "1126" "2144" "1805" "2211" "1722" "1874" "1721" "91"   "16"   "2451" "410"  "31"   "1153" "1593" "280"  "1878" "366"  "20"  
[201] "2407" "69"   "1605" "1606" "694"  "1881" "403"  "73"   "303"  "1149" "955"  "1144" "893"  "1138" "2221" "140"  "404"  "819"  "1365" "2225"
[221] "1374" "1690" "1485" "442"  "1150" "1614" "1486" "78"   "1894" "1998" "185"  "2236" "2229" "1373" "1155" "1369" "1817" "184"  "1305" "9"   
[241] "2017" "331"  "1910" "466"  "1621" "566"  "1619" "1372" "2239" "570"  "1908" "947"  "1906" "587"  "170"  "1629" "17"   "308"  "2112" "2257"
[261] "400"  "575"  "1166" "402"  "1745" "1733" "1818" "372"  "962"  "329"  "829"  "966"  "67"   "1174" "2248" "703"  "1622" "1624" "1623" "574" 
[281] "2255" "269"  "1013" "1180" "1387" "1627" "40"   "1924" "2270" "2260" "1631" "95"   "1628" "1184" "2423" "2050" "1481" "1388" "1037" "2060"
[301] "843"  "1746" "1202" "975"  "977"  "1392" "256"  "2109" "2541" "333"  "1495" "1047" "2426" "2478" "2277" "250"  "2282" "981"  "92"   "848" 
[321] "2290" "75"   "1995" "1646" "2143" "688"  "2123" "2488" "2499" "255"  "1941" "1190" "914"  "1189" "2487" "1911" "1768" "382"  "2305" "1512"
[341] "2113" "2127" "2329" "980"  "1203" "1204" "582"  "1949" "2185" "600"  "588"  "1422" "1468" "1963" "2425" "2331" "2494" "2122" "1273" "2415"
[361] "2147" "2335" "2500" "2276" "864"  "2397" "2504" "1235" "1269" "2361" "2360" "2119" "1009" "2371" "2362" "709"  "1976" "1216" "2039" "594" 
[381] "595"  "2517" "77"   "2124" "2373" "1680" "1682" "998"  "259"  "1984" "2386" "1785" "1683" "143"  "1990" "1179" "2163" "2418" "82"
```

I am not sure on how to remove the excessive leverage values from my data.

I've tried `df2 = df[which(names(df) %nin% remove),]` but I've had no success with that or minor variations. It removes more rows than there are too large leverage values, probably because it removes the values, not X'th observation.

Anyone has a basic R code for this? I seem to be lost.

Comment: This is quite possibly very bad statistics. You should possibly consider a transformation on your `y`. Without more details no trouble shooting can be done. The answer you are asking for is `df2 = df[!( lev > 2 * 8/2546),]`, which is likely not the answer you actually want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purely as a programming issue, you want `df[!which(rownames(df) %in% remove), ]`, as there is no `%nin%`. Also note, you want `row.names` not `names`, as you want to select rows not columns. Or, why not simply use `df[lev <= (2 * 8 / 2546), ]`?

In your specific context, the first one will give you wrong result. You have subset and overwritten  `df`, after which its `row.names` is no longer 1,2,3,....

Statistically, high leverage alone does not imply outliers. It is the combination of high leverage and big residual that is problematic. The Cook's Distance is a good measure on this.